# Is it possible for PHP to specify a particular future date and time, then echo HTML?

Tags: php, date, time, calendar, echo

**Basically, I want PHP to refer to a specific date and then echo the HTML below into the appropriate table cell on the calendar that corresponds to that date, i.e., specify August 16, 2014 and then echo the event information.**  You guys are so fast, I wasn't ready for you, ha!  :)

I have managed to make a calendar that only uses PHP and CSS and it seems to be working very well.  *Phew!*  I also would like to avoid Javascript and bypass the database, altogether, which I have managed to do up to this point.

I can use CSS tooltips to show events and I have them working with IOS.  This is my last hurdle:  is it possible for PHP to specify a particular date, say August 16, 2014 and then echo the following HTML, having it appear in the date-appropriate table cell?

```
<div class="has-tooltip">
Event
<span class="tooltip">Concert In The Park<br />
123 City Park Drive<br />
AnyTown, STATE 00000<br />
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">More Info</a><br />
or call 555.123.4567<br /></span>
</div>
```

No other users will be entering information; it's only for my personal use and I can always double-check before publishing.

The only actual hard-coded HTML that appears on my calendar page is `<body></body>`.  Everything else is echoed by PHP, so I can't very well just add the above to an existing table cell.

Thank you for any help!  :)

PHP CODE for calendar (without Tags):

```
$currMonth = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month']  : date('n');
$currYear  = isset($_GET['year'])  ? $_GET['year']   : date('Y');
$today = (($currYear == date('Y')) && ($currMonth == date('n'))) ? date('j') : 0;

$prevMonth = $currMonth==1 ? 12 : $currMonth-1;
$nextMonth = $currMonth==12?  1 : $currMonth+1;
$prevYear = $currMonth==1 ? $currYear-1 : $currYear;
$nextYear = $currMonth==12? $currYear+1 : $currYear;


$day1 = mktime(0,0,0,$currMonth,1,$currYear);
$dim = date('t', $day1);
$dayN = mktime(0,0,0,$currMonth,$dim,$currYear);
$dow1 = (date('w',$day1)+0) % 7;
$dowN = (date('w',$dayN)+0) % 7;
$calHead = date('F Y',$day1);
echo <<<EOT
    <div class="calwrapper">
    <div class="caltitle"><h1>Calendar</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="fnl first"></div>
    <div class="adjust"></div>
     <div class="fnl last"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="caldisplay">
    <table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="hd"><a class="cal_button" href="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?year=$prevYear&month=$prevMonth"> Prev </a></td>
      <td colspan="5" class="adjust">$calHead</td>
      <td class="hd"><a class="cal_button" href="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?year=$nextYear&month=$nextMonth"> Next </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="we">Sun</th>
      <th class="wd">Mon</th>
      <th class="wd">Tue</th>
      <th class="wd">Wed</th>
      <th class="wd">Thu</th>
      <th class="wd">Fri</th>
      <th class="we">Sat</th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
EOT;

for ($d=0;$d<$dow1;$d++) echo "<td class=\"hd\"> </td>";
$c = $dow1;
for ($d=1; $d<=$dim; $d++, $c++) {
    if ($c%7==0) echo "</tr><tr>";
    $cl = ($c%7==5) || ($c%7==6) ? 'we' : 'wd';
    $st = ($d == $today) ? "style='padding: 0px;'" : '';
    echo "<td class=\"$cl\" $st>\n";
    echo "$d" ;
    echo "</td>\n";
}
while ($c++ % 7 != 0) echo '<td class=\"hd\"> </td>';
echo "</tr></table>\n";
echo '</div></div>';
```

Comment: I'm finding your question really confusing.  I think I need more context.  I think it'd help if you posted more code.

Comment: I agree with Kai, need more info...It sounds like there is 2 topics. Have php give a future date and add this html via php echo to that specific date...am I correct?

Comment: `<?php $date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");?>` then `<div class="has-tooltip"><?php echo $date;?>...</div>` if that's what you're asking. For future date `$date = new DateTime("2014-08-16");
$date->modify("+7 day");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");`

Comment: Anybody can explain why this question is upvoted even its not clear.

Comment: So sorry; trying to figure out how the board works, ha!  Am I allowed to post my PHP code here?

Comment: @ Fred  That looks promising.  I'm not a coder, just a dumb musician.  Would you mind helping me to understand the breakdown of <?php $date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");?> (the 1 js portion)?  I just got taken away from this board by a major interruption and I'm coming across even more scattered than usual.        @Drew, yes, that's right.  If I can learn to call for the date of an upcoming event and then echo that basic HTML, I can just enter my events that way, instead of using the database or JS.  I hope.  :)

Comment: I'm actually both; coder AND musician, *go figure* ;) As for the future dating, the `date = new DateTime("2014-08-16"); $date->modify("+7 day"); echo $date->format("Y-m-d");` was an example. If you Google `$date->modify("+7 day")` you'll get a whole bunch of results, and/or you can look on PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php on the function. The example I gave you wasn't JS, but PHP in its *purest* form ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your for...while loop:

```
if (date('d/m/y') == '16/08/14') {
    echo 'Your table cell here';
}
```

you can find more information about the date function here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks so very much, guys!  The fog is lifting and I so appreciate the suggestions from Fred and Kenyon.  This will sort it for me.  :)

Comment: If this answer helped, or worked for you could please mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!